# Ошибка в скрипте с переменной

Tags: linux, bash

У меня есть начало скрипта.
Подскажите в чем проблема.

```
test.sh

#!/bin/bash
username=ppp
chown $username /home/$username
```

Получаю chown: неверный пользователь: «ppp\r»

Comment: У вас *DOS*'овский *line break* небось.

Comment: Попробуйте в `"` взять `ppp`

Comment: Попробовал "ppp", все то же самое

Comment: `sed -i 's/\r//g' /test.sh` исправит проблему с возвратом каретки

Comment: А пересоздал файл с тем же содержимым и все заработало. Подскажие, а в чем была проблема? Чтобы в будущем не попадать в такой просак.

Comment: @PotroNik, `man dos2unix`.

Comment: @0andriy у меня с ним проблемы были, когда путь указывался абсолютный, находясь в другой директории, он просто удалял содержимое файла, поэтому `sed ` на мой взгляд решение более надёжное

Answer (score 6, accepted):

В комментариях вам старшие товарищи написали, а потом вы же, по сути, подтвердили. Но им было лень разжевывать. А я попробую.

В Windows и Unix-подобных системах используются разные знаки перевода строки. Знак перевода строки - это такая штука, которая не выглядит как буква, но когда она в тексте есть, следующий символ пишется с новой строки. То, что вписывается в текстовый файл при нажатии клавиши Enter.

Так вот, в Windows там два байта, обозначаются они \r и \n. В десятичном представлении 13 и 10 соответственно. В linux там только \n, то есть, один байт.

Вы вписали в свой sh-скрипт строки с лишним байтом \r. Это не понравилось интерпретатору скрипта.

Когда же вы переписали сначала, символы перевода строки везде проставились правильные, только \n и никаких \r.

Comment: Большое спасибо

Comment: @picapica, вместо "спасибо", хоть оно, обычно, и приятно, лучше пометьте ответ как "Принятый". Для этого слева от ответа есть галочка. :)

Comment: @ЮрийКозлов, спасибо вам! :)